# Which of the following functions exist?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Which of the followings are **TRUE ?**

**(a)** Let , $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z^2$ be a bijection. Then there exists a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ which extends $f$.

**(b)** Let, $D$ be a closed unit disc in $\mathbb R^2$ . Then $\exists$ a continuous map $$f:D\setminus \{(0,0)\}\to \{x\in \mathbb R:|x|\le 1\}$$which is onto.

**(c)** Let, $D$ be a closed unit disc in $\mathbb R^2$. Then $\exists$ a continuous map $$f:D\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \{x\in \mathbb R:|x|>1\}$$ which is onto.

**(c)** **FALSE**. As $D\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is path-connected & hence connected , but $\{x\in \mathbb R:|x|>1\}$ is disconnected.

I think **(b)** is **TRUE** , but I can not find an example. I want an example or a proper justification from which we can say that such a function exists.

I have no idea about option **(a)**.

Comment: For (a): Do you mean $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ or $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Sorry..!! It was a typing mistake. I edited it..See now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b) Consider the map $f:D\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to [-1,1]$ where $f(x,y)=x$.

For (a) let $f(n)=a_n$.  For each $n\in\Bbb Z$, let $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ be given by $$f_n(t)=
\begin{cases}
(1-t)a_n+ta_{n+1}, & 0\le t<1\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
This $f_n(t)$ traces the line segment from $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$ for $0\le t<1$ and is $0$ every where else.

Now, let 
$$F(t)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}f_n(t-n)$$

We see that $F(n)=f_n(0)=a_n$. Also, $F(t)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Why does this not answer part b)?

Comment: My apologies, I see that the OP asked for an example. Let me delete the comment.

Comment: OK..What about option (a)?

Comment: That is true also. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For (a).  More generally, any map $f \colon \mathbb Z \to T$, where $T$ is arcwise connected, extends to a continuous map $f \colon \mathbb R \to T$.

Comment: How we can show $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is path connected?

Comment: No, use $T = \mathbb R^2$, which is path connected.

Comment: In My question $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z^2$

Comment: So first compose with inclusion $\mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @GEdgar do you have a proof that if T is path-connected then we can continuously extends our map to reals????if you have then please provide it I am unable to prove it!